# Does a conference poster count as a publication for PhD application?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, computer-science

I'm preparing a CV and required documents for PhD applications and I've been asked to provide references to publications. I've been wondering if it's appropriate and a good idea to put my student poster there?

The field is Computer Science and the poster has been presented during one of the top conferences. Posters were not part of proceedings and are not officially available (only online abstracts).

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a good idea to include such a poster in your CV or mention it elsewhere in your application (e.g. discuss it and the work in the personal statement). However, I would refrain from listing anything under "publications" unless it has been peer reviewed and published in a reputable journal.

I think in this particular case, the application is asking for references to papers rather than posters, but it may be worthwhile emailing the admissions people at the department to ask where you should include the poster.

Comment: "in a reputable journal" - In computer science, posters are often submitted together with a short paper, which is included in the conference proceedings. This would count as a (small) publication as well. But this case doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm thinking about putting it in CV under "Presentations", together with conference talks without peer-reviewed papers.

Comment: @thorek A separate section is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context, more specifically:

- What is the importance of such a poster in relation to your total list of published works? Do you believe that it was one of the top studies that you did ?
- Is there any *in progress* work that you are doing for expanding the work on this poster that you would like to cite in your application ?
- How relevant is this conference to the field you are applying ?

In my case, in my MsC application, I included my two conference posters in my CV as I did not have any relevant journal publication accepted at the time of the application. I would recommend using a different section for this, such as *Peer-Reviewed Publications* and *Conference Presentations* or *Conference Proceedings*. However, if you believe this is a minor work compared to what you have already produced I would not worry about that.

Lastly, I agree with @astronat that may be worthwhile contacting the department to ask what they are looking for in the application and how you could include this work to improve your CV.